# Flutter Text Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-widget

I have a simple screen with three text widgets and when the user click on one of these text widget that text should turn black font text color and other text widget color should not change.so i provide my code in the below and How can I implement on my code so that only the clicked text changes color.

> Main.Dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(myApp());
}

class myApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: HomeData(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeDataState createState() => _HomeDataState();
}

class _HomeDataState extends State<HomeData> {
  Color _textColor1 = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Demo",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  filterText();
                  setState(() {
                    _textColor1 = Colors.black;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  "All",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Text(
                "|",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  filterText();
                },
                child: Text(
                  "QR Codes",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Text(
                  "|",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  filterText();
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Bar Codes",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void filterText() {
    String filterAllText = "All";
    setState(() {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "$filterAllText",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 14.0);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the code bellow :

```
class _HomeDataState extends State<HomeData> {
  Color _textColor1 = Colors.black;
  Color _textColor2 = Colors.black26;
  bool _isCheckedAll = true;
  bool _isCheckedQr = false;
  bool _isCheckedBar = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Demo",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isCheckedAll = true;
                    _isCheckedQr = false;
                    _isCheckedBar = false;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  "All",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: _isCheckedAll ? _textColor1 : _textColor2,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Text(
                "|",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isCheckedAll = false;
                    _isCheckedQr = true;
                    _isCheckedBar = false;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  "QR Codes",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: _isCheckedQr ? _textColor1 : _textColor2,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Text(
                  "|",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isCheckedAll = false;
                    _isCheckedQr = false;
                    _isCheckedBar = true;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Bar Codes",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: _isCheckedBar ? _textColor1 : _textColor2,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```